# How to add SAN extension in certificate using Go

Tags: go, openssl, x509certificate, subject-alternative-name

I need to specify the registeredID in certificate.

So I add this in config file, when sign certificate using OpenSSL.

```
[ alternate_names ]
DNS.1 = localhost
RID.1 = 1.2.3.4.5.5
```

Here, `1.2.3.4.5.5` is OID.

I followed [How to format an OID Subject Alt Name entry in a openssl.cnf file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38030893/1924666) in Stack Overflow.

Now, I want to generate certificate in Go. Below one is my current config

```
cfg := cert.Config{
    CommonName:   name,
    Organization: []string{"Elasticsearch Operator"},
    AltNames: cert.AltNames{
        DNSNames: []string{
            "localhost",
        },
    },
    Usages: []x509.ExtKeyUsage{
        x509.ExtKeyUsageServerAuth,
        x509.ExtKeyUsageClientAuth,
    },
}
```

In this configuration, how can I add OID number.

Comment: `DNSNames: []string` seems like it might be too restrictive. [RFC 5280](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.6) provides more `GeneralNames` than the DNS name. Does Go have other `GeneralNames`, like `iPAddress`, `registeredID` or `rfc822Name`?

Comment: No.  I can't see any

Comment: Ouch... It looks like [`CreateCertificateRequest`](https://godoc.org/crypto/x509) and [`Certificate` type](https://golang.org/src/crypto/x509/x509.go#L623) provide some other `GeneralNames` like `EmailAddresses` and `IPAddresses`, but I don't see several of the other ones. Maybe you have to shell-out to the command line.

Answer (score 5):

There is no direct way to add OBJECT IDENTIFIER in certificate using Go.

We have found a custom solution.

Go provides an option to add additional SAN information in Certificate

```
x509.Certificate{
    ExtraExtensions: []pkix.Extension{
        {
            // Here, We add SAN additional with specific ID
        },
    },
}
```

According to [2.5.29.17 - Subject Alternative Name](http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/2.5.29.17.html), OID for SAN is `2.5.29.17`

Lets say, we will add registeredID `1.2.3.4.5.5` in SAN. And this RID needs to be added as Tag `#8`. (According to [2.5.29.17](http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/2.5.29.17.html))

So the byte value for this Extension is `[]byte{0x88, 0x05, 0x2A, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x05}`

Here,

- `0x88` is the tag value for context-specific `#8`
- `0x05` is length of the encoded value
- `0x2A, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x05` is encoded value of `1.2.3.4.5.5`

  - `0x2A` comes from `42` which is  `40 * 1 + 2`, here `1` and `2` are first two value of ID.

So, finally

```
rawValue := []asn1.RawValue{
    {FullBytes: []byte{0x88, 0x05, 0x2A, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x05}},
}
rawByte, _ := asn1.Marshal(rawValue)

_ = x509.Certificate{
    ExtraExtensions: []pkix.Extension{
        {
            Id:    asn1.ObjectIdentifier{2, 5, 29, 17},
            Value: rawByte,
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. It seems like the long term solution is for Go to support additional `GeneralNames`.